# Why isn't the first parameter for a method/constructor named?

Tags: objective-c, language-design

Take [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nstimer_class/reference/nstimer.html). When constructed all parameters, except the first, which is the method name, is named:

```
NSTimer *timer =
    [NSTimer
        scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: seconds
        target: self
        selector: @selector(timerTick:)
        userInfo: nil
        repeats: repeats
    ];
```

Why isn't the first parameter named? i.e.

```
NSTimer *timer =
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval
        interval: seconds
        target: self
        selector: @selector(timerTick:)
        userInfo: nil
        repeats: repeats
    ];
```

Is there some language design decision behind this? Does it offer some flexibility I cannot see here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really more accurate to say, as the Apple docs do, that an *"Objective-C method declaration includes the parameters as part of its name."*

The entire thing identifies the method. That's why the method you asked about starts with:

```
scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval
```

...so that it reads naturally without an additional name for the first parameter.

Source:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW1

As more of a sort of existential answer, the answer to *why* questions is often simply, "because that's how it was designed." The creators of Objective-C, one must presume, felt that this was a more readable way to declare methods than other ways of doing it. That's pretty much it.

Comment: Thanks. This makes more sense, in that weird strange way languages from the 80s make sense :)

Comment: Agreed: I might say "throw ball to sue" and most languages would have `throw( <type ball> ball, <type person> sue)` while obj-c prefers `throwBall(<type ball> ball, toPerson: <type Person> sue)`. ~forgive the incorrect syntax... I generally dislike method overloading but if you are defining a method by its parameters then I could see some logic to this design. Though ultimately, I agree - it really hurts readability because (1) the first parameter seems more privileged than the others and (2) it blends the action and the recipient of the action.

Answer (score 5):

I would argue that properly named Objective-C methods do in fact name the first parameter. In the example you gave, the 1st parameter has a name of `TimeInterval` while the base method name is `scheduledTimerWith`.

Keep in mind that the method could have actually been defined as:

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimer:(NSTimeInterval)seconds
                           :(id)target
                           :(SEL)aSelector
                           :(id)userInfo
                           :(BOOL)repeats
```

giving the method a name of `scheduledTimer:::::`.

Of course that's lame and unreadable so each parameter is given a name and we end up with `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` where the 1st parameter is named `TimeInterval`.

Comment: It's important to note that the method name is _not_ `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`. The method name is `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`. They aren't named parameters like in other languages, they are just segments of the method name.

Comment: @TomDalling Was your comment to me or the OP? If to me, I already stated that the method name is the full one with all of the colons.

Comment: I think it's just to clarify that you can sort of *think of* the first parameter as named `TimeInterval` but that's not what's really happening. Technically, it's all just part of the method name. That might be a bit pedantic, though.

Comment: I think in practice a lot of programmers still just think of them as parameters like in any other language.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very interesting question. I don't think there's much of an answer besides the fact that it's convention behind Objective-C. Additionally, for methods that have only one parameter, it would be shorter to call. For example:

```
[[MyObject alloc] init];
```

In the above call, you don't have to specify the name of the parameter.

Comment: The code you posted has no parameters for either method, not one parameter.

Comment: Right, in the example code you're calling the class method `alloc` (with no parameters) and sending the message `init` to the object it returns (again, with no parameters).